# What is this device?

Tags: electrical, appliances

It's a bit off topic, but let's see...

I live in a condo, and the devices pictured below are found everywhere: in flats, in corridors, even in the car park (they are attached to ceilings) and I have no clue what they are. Would anyone know ?
[image: thingy]

Comment: Is there any other writing/markings on the device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is in fact a [Wi-Fi Extender](http://www.walmart.com/ip/Wireless-Extenders-Omni-Directional-Wide-Band-Ceiling-Mount-Indoor-Antenna/39867685).

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing it is a different looking version of this:
[WiFi antenna](http://www.antennas.com/iflex-indoor-ap/)

Answer (score 1):

I would say that it is a covered sprinkler (fire extinguisher). It will react to temperature rise and start spraying water. The water jet will pop off the cover, which protects the sprinkler until it is needed.

Comment: That's a pretty good idea. Let me check if there are any visible sprinklers nearby these things when I'm back at home.

Comment: Missed, we have other sprinklers, so @Ross is probably right